# Sharekit is not working in iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, sharekit

am using sharekit for sharing images in facebook, twitter and email

in facebook correctly working. twitter and email is working in back of the uiview. ( see the below screen shot).

here you can see the twitter form is back side of UIview. 
for email also samething happening.see the email comtroller is back side of UIview.

here, am using  ***uiview for slideshow of image in uiviewcontroller***.

am using this code for connecting twitter

```
 SHKItem *twitterItem = [SHKItem image:mCurrentImageView.image title:@"Check out my photos! "];
    [SHKTwitter shareItem:twitterItem];
```

am using this code for connecting mail

```
 SHKItem *mail = [SHKItem image:mCurrentImageView.image title:@"Check out my photos! "];
            [SHKMail shareItem:mail];
```

were am wrong.. dont know help in this...

thanks in advance..

Comment: Am also using sharekit in my application. I donot have any problem. Am getting images with FB, twitter and mail. So check your view options.

Comment: if you found an answer can you plz share, i have the same problem with email and i dont know whats wrong. There is no error, just the send email view disapears just as it should. but i never get  the email.

Answer (score 1):

There  is not the problem any ShareKit.  Check Your view setting or Try to create New view.